# Page must refresh after seconds set in php variable

Tags: php

I've been through the forum and tried this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128417/stop-javascript-auto-refresh-after-fix-time-for-example-1-min).

I'm busy with a testing site.  Different tests has different time limits, eg test A = 3600 and test B = 2400 which is stored in a table.  When the test is started the time is stored in a variable.  What I am trying to achieve is that the page needs to refresh after 3600 or 2400 depending on the test or run a script that checks if the time has expired and log the user out.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Currently I am using

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

which works but how do I change it for test B then?

Comment: if you can reach that table so just take the value when the page is loaded and put it into  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?=$value?>">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calculating the time until the refresh in php, using a `<meta>` tag to simulate an http header seems a bit weird to me. Just send the header straight away:

```
<?php
header('Refresh: ' . $timeLimit);
```

Comment: People do seem to forget about that. While 'Refresh' is not part of the HTTP standard, it is adopted by most/all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If the test A and test B are in two different variables (say, `$variableA` and `$variableB`) just use the following.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $variableA; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

If the refresh interval is in a PHP variable called `$refresh`, this should do:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $refresh?>">
```

Comment: Ok thank you all, I was not aware that I could use the variable in the header, stupid of me though!