# Javascript that refresh the page when the server time hits zero

Tags: php, javascript

I'm looking for a javascript that refreshes the page when the server time hits zero (every hour).

Comment: How accurate does it need to be ?

Comment: Not that accurate, just if its refreshes after a hour (seconds or so doesn't matter) is enough.

Comment: You need an ajax petition to check the time in the server, but considerer that ajax is async.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be accurate just set a timeout when the page loads with the remaining time.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599189/page-must-refresh-after-seconds-set-in-php-variable

Comment: and where were you looking so far? this website here is more about programming questions not looking questions btw.

Comment: Come on guys, no need to vote down. He is new to SO. Just flag if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
$diff = mktime(date("H") + 1, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")) - time();
echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="' . $diff . '" />');
```

But keep in mind to separate your business from your view logic ;-)

(You can also omit the "date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")" which i added to help understanding the code)

If you want to use Javascript, just use a setTimeout with a one second interval which counts the Value from $diff down to 0;

Answer (score 0):

If the page just needs to refresh after an hour, the server can set meta tag in the page header when the page is first served:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

where 3600 is an hour in seconds. If you want it on the hour, as opposed to after an hour, the server can set the number of seconds to be the number of seconds until the next hour (e.g if the server time is 10:30, it would set it to 1800.

Comment: I know that, but it needs to be when to clock hit zero, it's a javascript in a php file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways as I know.

1. If you know the timezone of the server (and it is fixed) get time in js of the timezone, and set countdown to nearest hour (there are [libraries](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/jquery-countdown-scripts.html) for that ).
2. Second option is that you set a meta of tag in page header in your php code to current time of the server. And then use that to countdown.

Option 1 would be more accurate as you would get the current time related to time-zone as opposed to second option because there would be a delay as to when the server adds the meta and when does your js reads it.

But option 2 is more favorable if your server location can possibly change.